# There was no/not a/not any

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between **there was no, there was not a** and **there was not any**?

- Yesterday I visited a very undevelopped 
  area in my tour of Africa. I rented a room in a hotel there. The hotel lacked basic facilites. There was **no television set/ not a television set/ not any television** set in the room.

  - To negate the sentence "there are some televison sets in The US." We can say either "There are **not any/no television sets** in The US."

But To negate the sentence "there is a twlevision set in my room.", is there only one way? Is there another way to say "there is no television in my room."

Can any teacher or expert please answer this?

Comment: For all practical purposes all three phrases mean the same thing.  sometimes, 'there was **not** a' and 'there was not **any**' are sometimes used with an emphasis on 'not' or on 'any' to show our surprise at a particular situation, but this does not change the meaning of what was said.

Comment: There is no practical difference. Except that idiomatically, *there wasn't* is normally used instead of *there was not* (or *there aren't* instead of *there are not*).