# 'no' vs. 'not any'

Tags: any

Is there any difference between the following 2 sentences, please?

- I have not received any feedback from any party
- I have received no feedback from any party

Thank you

Comment: See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/192631/there-was-no-not-a-not-any) and others (search on 'not any').

Comment: To be fair, @KateBunting, the question you linked has no (not any?) answers, only comments.