# "no" vs "not any"

Tags: grammar, determiners, emphasis

Is there any difference between the following sentences (e.g. in emphasis), or are they effectively interchangeable?

Example 1:

```
We found no differences between their reports.
We did not find any differences between their reports.
```

Example 2:

```
I received no email.
I did not receive any email.
```

OBS: I am aware that similar questions have been asked before (e.g. [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/319255/no-vs-not-any) and [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/192631/there-was-no-not-a-not-any)), but I didn't find any (or, I found no) satisfactory answer.

Comment: It's a stylistic choice whether to negate the *noun* *(**no** email)* or the *verb* *(did **not** receive)*. In your context, the word ***any*** is effectively an optional "intensifying determiner" for the following noun in *I did not receive [**an, the, any,** NOTHING] email.*

Comment: Because plural nouns usually go with the "zero article" *(NOTHING),* you'd either include optional intensifying ***any*** in the first example (the idiomatic default) or you wouldn't have any determiner at all. *We did not find differences between their reports* is less likely, but perfectly valid. But if ***no*** difference was found, that would more naturally be referenced in the singular anyway: *We did not find **a difference** between their reports.*

Answer (score 1):

Practically there is no difference, and it is just a peculiarity of English that there are two ways to negate "We found some differences".

*Possibly* "I've received no email" is marginally more formal and appropriate to written English, whereas "I haven't received any email" is spoken. But the difference in formality is marginal at most.

Comment: Hi! I upvoted your good answer. Is it wrong to write in an essay "I haven't received any email"?

Comment: Per my comment under the question, ***any*** is an "intensifier". Note that ***email*** is like, say, ***payment***, in that it can be a countable or uncountable noun. If I include the intensifier in *I don't receive **any** payment for posting to ELL*, that makes the assertion more "forceful". If that's the impression you want to give in your essay, include the intensifier. Just note that you don't *have* to include it.

Comment: Yes, it would be fine in an essay.

Comment: @James K Thank you very much!