# on jumping over the puddle versus upon jumping over the puddle: is the action completed or underway?

Tags: prepositions, progressive-aspect, perfect-aspect

> Upon jumping over the puddle...
>
> On jumping over the puddle...

Is the jump  completed or underway? And do the prepositions **on** and **upon** have the same  meaning in that respect?

> Upon jumping over the puddle she misjudged how wide it was and stepped into the water.
>
> On jumping over the puddle she misjudged how wide it was and stepped into the water.

Are both sentences idiomatic? Only one of them? Neither of them?

Comment: Are you asking about those two exact phrases, or are you trying to learn how "upon" and "on" work?

Comment: On or upon is the same thing but upon is more formal and in writing.

Comment: I am asking about the aspectual aspects, if any, of **upon|on** with an **-ing** form. Is the action completed or underway?

Answer (score 1):

Either preposition (or none) is fine for the OP's context. There's virtually no difference between ***on*** and ***upon*** except that the latter is a bit more "literary, poetic", so it would be unlikely in a conversational context.

One slight difference between including a preposition before the participle clause *(**doing** something)* or not is that the preposition-based versions tend to imply ***immediately after** doing it*, where no preposition often implies ***while** doing it*.

Comment: If the prepositions imply *immediately after*, i.e. the act has been completed,  don't those sentences seem discordant? Immediately after jumping over the puddle she misjudged how wide it was?

Comment: *On jumping over the puddle she misjudged how wide it was* is a ***highly*** suspect utterance! (Precisely because of that ***immediately after*** implication.) More sensibly, *On **attempting to jump** over the puddle she misjudged how wide it was (and failed to jump over it).*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hi! I upvoted your good answer! I am very sad because you didn't give me your email address.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hi! In that question you said that the sentence "We did not find differences between their reports" is less likely.How you know that?  [1]:https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/341751/no-vs-not-any

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou: I know because I'm a native speaker, But [here's a relevant usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=found+no+difference%2Cdid+not+find+any+difference%2Cdid+not+find+any+differences%2Cdid+not+find+differences&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) if you need convincing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hi! You compared the sentences "We did not find differences between their reports" and "We did not find any differences between their reports" and you got confused and you said that the sentence "We did not find differences between their reports" is less likely. The sentence "We did not find any differences between their reports" is less likely.Do you agree with me?

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou: I don't understand what you're getting at. As my link clearly shows, we normally negate the (singular) noun ***difference*** rather than the verb ***found*** in such contexts, so why would anyone care which of the *less common* is more likely to occur at all. Just learn the more common form and forget the rest.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hi! I asked you because I want to understand your opinion! I admire you! You are clever and you give good answers in this site! Please, don't take me wrong. I am a friend of yours! You said that if no difference was found we say "We did not find a difference between their reports". Is it wrong to say "We did not find differences between their reports" or "We did not find any differences between their reports" if no difference was found?

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou: All your 3 alternatives are syntactically valid, as is the "missing" 4th (***any*** + singular) permutation "We did not find any difference between their reports". Most people in most contexts wouldn't notice or care which phrasing you used. I'm simply making the point that even though most native speakers aren't consciously aware of it, they normally negate the *noun*, not the verb. You yourself wrote *You said that **if no difference was found** we say...* You didn't write *You said that if **a difference was / differences were NOT found** we say...* So you got it right!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hi! I have understood what you are trying to explain to me! Thank you very much! You said that we have the idiomatic default when we say "We did not find any differences between their reports". I don't understand you. Is there any idiom in that sentence? How can I write that sentence in order to not have the idiomatic default? Maybe I don't understand the meaning of "idiomatic default". Could you please tell me what is the meaning of "idiomatic default"?

Comment: In this context, "idiomatic default" simply means the most likely words a native speaker will use in any given context. It *doesn't* necessarily imply there's anything wrong with using different words. Note that "idiomatic" here just means "what people typically say, the most common phrasing". It's not quite the same as *"That's a piece of cake"*, which is called an "idiom" because the *actual* meaning *("That's **easy**")* can't be understood just from the *literal* meanings of the words.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hi!Thank you very much! I have understood the meaning of the context "idiomatic default" but I didn't manage to find in a dictionary  the meaning of the word "default". Is there any dictionary that says the meaning of the word "default"? I have understood that "default" means "case". Am I right?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hi! Is it wrong if I say that the sentences ""We did not find a difference between their reports","We did not find differences between their reports", "We did not find any differences between their reports"and" We found no difference/differences between their reports" are all idiomatic defaults but the last one is the most idiomatic default because we usually negate the noun "difference" and not the verb "find" . Please tell me your opinion as a native speaker!